# jQuery Status change True false Image Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is My JQuery Code To Bind html table.I have two image...How can i check when `true` `1.jpg` show and when `false` `2.jpg` show.

```
$(function () {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebForm5.aspx/BindDatatable",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (dt) {
            debugger;
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.d.length; i++) {
                $("#example1 > tbody").append("<tr><td> <input type='checkbox' class='chk' id=" + dt.d[i].CategoryID + " /></td><td>" + dt.d[i].CategoryID + "</td><td>" + dt.d[i].Name + "</td><td><input type='image'if() src='images/1.png'title='Deactivate this'  value=" + dt.d[i].Status + " alt='Submit' width='18' height='18'>  </td><td> <i class='ui-tooltip fa fa-pencil' onclick='btnQueryString_Click(" + dt.d[i].CategoryID + ")' style='font-size:22px;margin-left: 32px;'></i><i class='ui-tooltip fa fa-trash-o' onclick='deleteRecord(" + dt.d[i].CategoryID + ")' style='font-size: 22px;margin-left: 32px;'></i> </tr>");
            }
            $("#example1").DataTable();
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

I am taking a image `<input type='image'>` tag.

```
<input type='image' src='images/1.png'title='Deactivate this'  value=" + dt.d[i].Status + " alt='Submit' width='18' height='18'>
```

Guide me how can i check the status value is it true or false and how to show it in table Status column??
Note:If i am using only using `+ dt.d[i].Status +` it shows OUTPUT `True` or `False` in Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first,

- The last `</td>` is missing
- Remove `if()` from the input element, that's invalid html
- Replace `'` with `\'` and `"` with `'` to keep the format intact

So, putting something like this inside your for loop should work

```
var image='';
if( dt.d[i].Status == true ) {
  image = '1.jpg';
}else{
  image = '2.jpg';
}

var data = '<tr>  <td> <input type=\'checkbox\' class=\'chk\' id=' + dt.d[i].CategoryID + ' /></td><td>' + dt.d[i].CategoryID + '</td>  <td>' + dt.d[i].Name + '</td>  <td><input type=\'image\' '+ image +' src=\'images/unblock.png\' title=\'Deactivate this\' value=' + dt.d[i].Status + ' alt=\'Submit\' width=\'18\' height=\'18\'> </td>  <td>     <i class=\'ui-tooltip fa fa-pencil\' onclick=\'btnQueryString_Click(' + dt.d[i].CategoryID + ')\' style=\'font-size:22px;margin-left: 32px;\'></i>    <i class=\'ui-tooltip fa fa-trash-o\' onclick=\'deleteRecord(' + dt.d[i].CategoryID + ')\' style=\'font-size: 22px;margin-left: 32px;\'></i>    </td></tr>';

$("#example1 > tbody").append(data);
```

Comment: unblock.png is my 1.png..so you just tell me what is the code

Comment: Can you please make your comment more clear? I really don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: can you write down the code clearly..please write down var data=....,this line clearly,so that i can implement..You just look my code and write down..

Comment: @Manoj Maharana, I'm glad I helped you.